Where do i put this method?
I'm new to java and just wanted to read a csv file and i did it. But i wanted to play with methods and i can't.
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CSVToObjectConverter {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String csvFile = args[0];
        String line;
        List<pizza> pizl = new ArrayList<>();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] data = line.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
                float pizza_id = Float.parseFloat(data[0]);
                float order_id = Float.parseFloat(data[1]);
                String pizza_name_id = data[2];
                float quantity = Float.parseFloat(data[3]);
                String order_date = data[4];
                String order_time = data[5];
                float unit_price = Float.parseFloat(data[6]);
                float total_price = Float.parseFloat(data[7]);
                String pizza_size = data[8];
                String pizza_category = data[9];
                String pizza_ingredients = data[10];
                String pizza_name = data[11];

                pizza pizaA = new pizza(pizza_id,
                order_id,
                pizza_name_id,
                quantity,
                order_date,
                order_time,
                unit_price,
                total_price,
                pizza_size,
                pizza_category,
                pizza_ingredients,
                pizza_name);
                pizl.add(pizaA);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       // for (pizza pizaA : pizl) {
           // System.out.println(pizl.get(0).order_id());
       // }
        /*
        public void myMethod() {
            for ( int a = 0 ; a < pizl.size() ; a++)
            {
                System.out.println(pizl.get(a).order_id());
            }
       }
       */

       myMethod(pizl);

    }

}

class Pizza{
    private float pizza_id;
    private float order_id;
    private String pizza_name_id;
    private float quantity;
    private String order_date;
    private String order_time;
    private float unit_price;
    private float total_price;
    private String pizza_size;
    private String pizza_category;
    private String pizza_ingredients;
    private String pizza_name;

    public pizza(float pizza_id,
    float order_id,
    String pizza_name_id,
    float quantity,
    String order_date,
    String order_time,
    float unit_price,
    float total_price,
    String pizza_size,
    String pizza_category,
    String pizza_ingredients,
    String pizza_name) {
        this.pizza_id = pizza_id;
        this.order_id = order_id;
        this.pizza_name_id = pizza_name_id;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.order_date = order_date;
        this.order_time = order_time;
        this.unit_price = unit_price;
        this.total_price = total_price;
        this.pizza_size = pizza_size;
        this.pizza_category = pizza_category;
        this.pizza_ingredients = pizza_ingredients;
        this.pizza_name = pizza_name;
    }

    // Getters and setters (omitted for brevity)

    //@Override
    public float pizza_id() {
        return pizza_id;
    }
    public float order_id() {
        return order_id;
    }
    public String pizza_name_id() {
        return pizza_name_id;
    }
    public float quantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public String order_date() {
        return order_date;
    }
    public String order_time() {
        return order_time;
    }
    public float unit_price() {
        return unit_price;
    }
    public float total_price() {
        return total_price;
    }
    public String pizza_size() {
        return pizza_size;
    }
    public String pizza_category() {
        return pizza_category;
    }
    public String pizza_ingredients() {
        return pizza_ingredients;
    }
    public String pizza_name() {
        return pizza_name;
    }

    public void myMethod(List<pizza> c) {
        for ( int a = 0 ; a < c.size() ; a++)
        {
            System.out.println(c.get(a).order_id());
        }
    }
}

I just want to use "myMethod" but i don't know how to.
I tried to move this method but i actually don't know where to put it and the output is an error that you cannot find symbol.
I need a hand with methods and java in general, but i don't have much time left for a task.

Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

You need to make this method static:
public static void myMethod(List<pizza> c) {
    for ( int a = 0 ; a < c.size() ; a++)
    {
        System.out.println(c.get(a).order_id());
    }
}

Then in main, you need to call (please also note that in JAVA class name must be Pizza not pizza)
Pizza.myMethod(pizl);


Yes: if your method is not static, it needs to be applied to a particular instance of Pizza, and it's not the case here.

You defined a method myMethod on the class Pizza. That means you need a Pizza object on which to invoke that method.
Pizza pizza = new Pizza( … ) ;
pizza.myMethod( … ) ;

But your method makes no sense being a part of the Pizza class. Your method takes a list of Pizza objects as an argument, to dump information on each to the console. So your method has nothing to do with any one Pizza object. That method belongs somewhere else, somewhere that deals with multiple Pizza objects. (See example code at bottom below.)
By the way, if the main purpose of your class is to transparently communicate shallowly-immutable data, then make it a record. As a convenient side-effect, the code collapses to a single line.
record Pizza ( float order_id, String pizza_name_id, float quantity, … ) {}

Also by the way, your types here make no sense. Using a fractional floating-point type like float makes no practical sense as an identifier. Ditto for quantity — Do customers order 1.028 of a pizza? You need to learn the difference between integer numbers and floating-point numbers (and accurate fractional numbers, BigDecimal used for money matters, etc.).
record Pizza ( int order_id, String pizza_name_id, int quantity, … ) {}

Furthermore you have collapsed order information such as order id, order time, and so on into the Pizza class. That info belongs in an Order class. The Pizza class is about just pizza pies, and a single pie at that. The Pizza class knows nothing of customers and the ordering process.
record Pizza ( int id , int size , List< String > ingredients , … ) {}  // The `id` here identifies one particular pie being made, *not* the order.

In real work, we would likely define an enum for the ingredients rather than use mere text (String objects). But that may be beyond your learning so far if you are a beginner.
An Order class should be written to track info about who ordered what when.
record Order ( int id , Instant whenPlaced , Customer customer , List< Pizza > pizzas , … ) {} 

Example usage:
List< Pizza > pies = 
    List.of
    (
        new Pizza ( 1 , 12 , List.of( "cheese" , "red sauce" , "Canadian Bacon" , "Pineapple" ) , … ) ,
        new Pizza ( 2 , 16 , List.of( "cheese" , "red sauce" , "Pepperoni" ) , … ) 
    );
Order order = new Order ( 1 , Instant.now() , new Customer( "Alice" ) , pies , … ) ;

In real work, some other software, such as a database, would be generating the sequence of ID numbers. Or we would use a UUID instead of a sequential integer as the identifier. But hard-coding numbers here works for our simplistic example.
 Back to the main point of your Question… The Order class here might have a method like your myMethod to print a list of order IDs in a certain format to give to the manager.
Let's make an oversimplified stab at a manager report. Such a report is likely to be found on a class that represents each shift each day at the pizzeria.
record Shift ( LocalDate date , List< Order > orders ) 
{
    void reportToManager() 
    {
        for ( Order order : orders )
        {
            System.out.println( "Order # " + order.id + " Quantity Pies: " + order.pizzas.size() ) ;
        }
    }
} 

Usage:
Shift shift = new Shift ( LocalDate.of( 2024 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) , ordersPulledFromDatabase ) ;
shift.reportToManager() ;

